Usar ApplicationUser dentro de ControllerBase en una Blazor Web App
Estoy probando Blazor Web App con cuentas de usuarios y he personalizado la clase UserInfo y ApplicationUser a las cuales le he añadido dos propiedades string (Nombre, IdProfesor), he modificado las tablas correspondientes y ahora quiero acceder a estas propiedades desde dentro de un método de webapi (ControllerBase)
He modificado la clase PersistingServerAuthenticationStateProvider del server y he añadido las dos propiedades:
    private async Task OnPersistingAsync()
        {
        if (authenticationStateTask is null)
            {
            throw new UnreachableException($"Authentication state not set in {nameof(OnPersistingAsync)}().");
            }

        var authenticationState = await authenticationStateTask;
        var principal = authenticationState.User;

        if (principal.Identity?.IsAuthenticated == true)
            {
            var userId = principal.FindFirst(options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType)?.Value;
            var email = principal.FindFirst(options.ClaimsIdentity.EmailClaimType)?.Value;
            var roles = principal.FindAll(options.ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType).Select(s=>s.Value);
            var user = _userManager.GetUserAsync(principal);

            if (userId != null && email != null)
                {
                state.PersistAsJson(nameof(UserInfo), new UserInfo
                    {
                    UserId = userId,
                    Email = email,
                    IdProfesor = user!.Result!.IdProfesor,
                    Roles = roles,
                    Nombre=  user!.Result!.Nombre
                    });
                }
            }
        }

He modificado la clase PersistentAuthenticationStateProvider del cliente:
public PersistentAuthenticationStateProvider(PersistentComponentState state)
    {
    if (!state.TryTakeFromJson<UserInfo>(nameof(UserInfo), out var userInfo) || userInfo is null)
        {
        return;
        }
    
    
    List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim> {
  new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userInfo.UserId),
  new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userInfo.Email),
  new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, userInfo.Email),
  new Claim("Nombre",userInfo.Nombre),
  new Claim("IdProfesor",userInfo.IdProfesor)
  };
for (int i = 0; i < userInfo!.Roles!.Count(); i++)
        {
        string role = userInfo!.Roles.ElementAt(i);
  claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role,role));
    }

    authenticationStateTask = Task.FromResult(
            new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims,
                    authenticationType: nameof(PersistentAuthenticationStateProvider)))));
    }

Y esto funciona desde dentro de un componente blazor, puedo acceder al Nombre y IdProfesor perfectamente
Desde un web api podría hacer esto y se que funciona:

Injectar el ManagerUser
y luego con User.Identity!.Email recuperar el usuario.

Pero no hay alguna forma de acceder a ese IdProfesor y Nombre?
Tambien he intentado añadir un Claim en PersistingServerAuthenticationStateProvider del server, pero no lo debo hacer bien, porque se pierde el valor.
Saludos.

Para acceder a las propiedades IdProfesor y Nombre dentro de un controlador API en Blazor Web App, puedes agregar estos valores como claims personalizados en el servidor, para luego recuperarlos desde el contexto del usuario en tu controlador.
Haz unos cambios al código en el servidor para agregar los claims personalizados (IdProfesor y Nombre):
Servidor (modificar el método OnPersistingAsync:
if (principal.Identity?.IsAuthenticated == true)
{
    var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(principal);
    var claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity;

    claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("IdProfesor", user!.IdProfesor ?? ""));
    claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("Nombre", user!.Nombre ?? ""));

    // Guardar la información del usuario como siempre
    var userId = principal.FindFirst(options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType)?.Value;
    var email = principal.FindFirst(options.ClaimsIdentity.EmailClaimType)?.Value;
    var roles = principal.FindAll(options.ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType).Select(s => s.Value);

    if (userId != null && email != null)
    {
        state.PersistAsJson(nameof(UserInfo), new UserInfo
        {
            UserId = userId,
            Email = email,
            IdProfesor = user!.IdProfesor,
            Roles = roles,
            Nombre = user!.Nombre
        });
    }
}

Dentro del controlador WebAPI puedes acceder a los claims personalizados asi:
[Authorize]
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class YourController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("userinfo")]
    public IActionResult GetUserInfo()
    {
        var idProfesor = User.FindFirst("IdProfesor")?.Value;
        var nombre = User.FindFirst("Nombre")?.Value;

        return Ok(new { IdProfesor = idProfesor, Nombre = nombre });
    }
}


Gracias por la solución. Ya lo había solucionado pero haciendo esto mismo en el ExternalLogin.

¡Genial! Por favor, marca la pregunta como respondida. De esta manera, otros podrán encontrarla fácilmente cuando la busquen y podremos ayudar a otros. ¡Gracias!
